# Generation of institution names

Tags: named-entity-recognition, text-generation

I have found a number of parsers for the automatic extraction of institution names from texts (e.g. [this one](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/extract-company-names-job-titles-from-free-text?newreg=8e35fba3c81049ec8a1e513ad87a127a)). My task is in a sense the inverse one: I want to automatically generate reality-like institution names, with a possibility to differentiate them by type (private-held, public, educational, etc.) and by branch.

Is there any algorithm / application / papers to be found? Alternatively, is there any (free access) database with such data?

Comment: Do you mean generate fictional entities? Anyway it's not really the inverse of NER, because NER relies on the context words in a sentence to detect entities names. In theory NER should work as well with fictional entities than with real ones (except that it knows some real ones from the training).

Comment: Important question: do you have training data? A.k.a institution namesz differentiated by type

Comment: Thanks Erwan, thanks Guillermo. I do understand that what I want is not exactly the inverse of NER, therefore the question. And no, I do mean "fictional" names. I do not have therefore any training data, but just a vague idea of classification (Private Company vs. Public Institution vs. Educational etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Conditional on you having data, yes, you can. Check out Generative Adversarial Networks and/or Reinforcement Learning for text generation. This paper is a good starting point: https://openreview.net/forum?id=rJedV3R5tm.

Also, [here](https://github.com/topics/text-generation)'s a tool that might help you. What you can do is generat these institution names without differentiating by type, and then build another model to classify them.

Comment: Guillermo, many thanks for the link. Highly interesting; the stuff ins very new to me, so I will probably need more time to digest (I did a random text generator myself once - but without almost any science).
If I am not mistaken, however, the second link does not lead to any tool, but to the paper itself - am I wrong?

Comment: Thanks Alex! You are right, my mistake. The link points to the tool now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build your own dataset, you could look at packages such as:

- [Faker](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/)
- [Mimesis](https://mimesis.readthedocs.io/)

They both provide features to generate company/institution names based on certain locales as well.

If your goal is to generate training data for a NER task, this should be a good start. If it's to generate company names, this will already cover quite a bit.

Comment: Thanks Valentin, I have already had a look at Mimesis, seems to be very attractive; Faker is a bit more complicated for me, as I am not a native Pythonese speaker (rether C#). But I am going to take some time to look at it, too.