# Generation of medical institution names: training corpora?

Tags: python, named-entity-recognition, text-generation

My question is quite similar to this one: [Generation of institution names](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/76388/generation-of-institution-names). I need to be able to produce 'fake' names of **medical** **institutions**, specifically to create data for unit tests. Unfortunately, simple tools like Faker do not work well for this task, so I am interested in a more sophisticated solution, possibly involving some NER model(s). My question here is where can I get text corpora for training the model? The texts must contain (human-)recognizable names of medical institutions, preferably in a number of languages. I have seen allusions that this might be done by scraping PubMed or other Web sources - are there possibly some concrete examples or howtos?

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a couple options to collect a sample of medical institutions:

- Wikipedia has [a list of hospitals by country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_hospitals) (isn't Wikipedia amazing?)
- Many countries have some kind of national directory of medical institutions, but that would probably be difficult to scrap and specific to each country.
- [UMLS](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/research/umls/index.html) has a category ("semantic group") for "Health Care Related Organization" (T093, see [here](https://lhncbc.nlm.nih.gov/semanticnetwork/download/SemGroups.txt)), which means that a list of such organizations can be directly collected from the UMLS data. I thought this would be a good option, but I did a quick test and it appears to contain only names of departments, no proper nouns, for example:

  ```
  Community occupational therapy clinic
  Abortion Center
  Area Health Education Center
  ```

Given that UMLS is closely related to PubMed, my guess is that it's not a very good direction, but maybe I didn't dig deep enough. Fair warning: Processing the whole PubMed/PMC is quite a lot of work in my experience.

Comment: Thanks Erwan, both suggestions are helpful! In the mean time, I have found a way to directly request the NCBI RESTful API, as in this [link](https://dataguide.nlm.nih.gov/eutilities/utilities.html). I am writing more about this in my answer below

Comment: I will write a Python script to mine these data, if someone is interested, feel free to contact me.

Comment: BTW, the wikipedia list of hospitals is far from complete. I checked for the two areas I know well, and the coverage is certainly less than 20% of what there is.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a way to create the corpus of potentially medical institutions by requesting the NCBI RESTful server, following the description in [this link](https://dataguide.nlm.nih.gov/eutilities/utilities.html).

First, you send an ESearch request containing some searching criteria (e.g. 'radiology', 'dicom', 'segmentation' - or whatever). As a response you obtain an XML document with a list of PubMed Ids.

Then you can send a EFetch request containing the IDs, and as a response you will obtain an XML document with an  tag for each author. That data can then be used to build the corpus (in the 1st approximation)